# Prop reactivity not working when passed from blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I attempted to pass a prop from Blade file to Vuejs component name `AppMessages`

```
<app-messages :messages="{{ $messages }}"></app-messages>
```

Then messages are being rendered based on `selfOwned` boolean.

```
 <app-message v-for="message in messages" :message="message" :key="message.id" v-if="message.selfOwned === false"></app-message>
 <app-message-own v-for="message in messages" :message="message" :key="message.id" v-if="message.selfOwned === true"></app-message-own>
```

in the child component, I pass a message when created by a Bus event

```
 let tempBuitMessage = this.tempMessage()
 Bus.$emit('message.added', tempBuitMessage);
```

define this.messages in props

```
 export default {
props: {
    messages: {
        required: true,
        type: Array
    }
},
```

in the parent component `AppMessages` I set up the listner

```
mounted() {
    Bus.$on('message.added', data => {
        this.messages.unshift(data)
        console.log(this.messages)
    });
},
```

**Issue**:

I expected the new passed message to but up in the chat but I can see it in the console (no error) but not rendered.

Comment: Can you show where this.messages is defined please.

Comment: can you please check my question again I just updated it

Comment: Sorry, I am a little unclear. Is that definition in the props of app-messages? Because you cannot manipulate your own props in a component. I am assuming this is why you arent getting reactivity, and since it is an array you are likely not getting a warning.

Comment: Not 100% sure but i will give you an answer hopefully you can refactor to.

Comment: Ok, try that. Not 100%, since Vue's reactivity gets real weird with arrays and with objects some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manipulate a component's props from within the component. Data flows down to children through props, and up to parents through events (not talking about a bus).

You should be able to get reactivity using a computed property, or just assigning messages on mount to a data property.

```
<template>
...
 <app-message v-for="message in model" :message="message" :key="message.id" v-if="message.selfOwned === false"></app-message>
 <app-message-own v-for="message in model" :message="message" :key="message.id" v-if="message.selfOwned === true"></app-message-own>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'app-messages',

    props: {
        messages: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            model: null,
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.model = this.messages;
    },

    mounted() {
        Bus.$on('message.added', data => {
            this.model.unshift(data)
            console.log(this.messages)
        });
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you :) may I know the reason why I can't modify props from child component?

Comment: It is a design choice of vue. Updating a prop like that isnt "watched". See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Organizing-Components and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad